# Implementing WCF Service using HTTP protocol with encryption

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

I need to implement WCF Service using HTTP protocol with encryption. Either message or transport security will do. Am I required to use x509 certificate to achieve security requirements for encryption? Or is there another way?

Comment: You only need a shared secret to implement encryption. How do you plan on the client and server agreeing on/getting the secret? Are you sure the users of the service will trust it given that it's using HTTP rather than HTTPS. Most (non-techie) people just assume HTTP insecure, HTTPS secure.

Comment: Some kind of shared key will be enough. I'm doing a pilot project and due to time constraints I'm unsure I will be able to implement certificate + SSL security properly. I'm looking for a fastest way to satisfy encryption requirements using HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use Transport security, not Message security. Transport security works just like regular https encryption - in fact, the URL to your host will be https. It's a little complicated to set up and get the certs and program configured correctly, but Transport has a big advantage over Message security.

With Message security, you must manually install the public key file of your x509 certificate on each of the client machines, and the public and private keys on the host machine, in order to get message security working. This means a lot of extra work - i.e. all the client cert file installations. Plus, since Message security is SOAP-based, you'll have to code everything along the SOAP lines, making REST programming difficult or impossible.

With Transport, you don't need to install copies of the cert public key on each client machine; just as with a normal https web server, the host transmits the public key to the client it first makes your connection.

Here's a link to a decent how-to article on https over wcf: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36705/Seven-simple-steps-to-enable-HTTPS-on-WCF-WsHttp-b

Comment: Using key files is better when I do not have a certificate?

Comment: The key files are the certificate ... a cert has two parts, the public key and the private key. When you log onto a https site, you'll get a copy of the public key sent to your browser by the host server. Your browser will use the public key (resident in the browsers memory) to create an encrypted "tunnel" between itself and the host. Only the host has the private key.

Comment: Now, if you're using HTTPS over WCF, the process is the same - the host will send the public key portion of the cert to the client automatically during the handshake process. But if you're using Message security, the public key as a literal file must be loaded on the client and registered. That's what sucks about message security; all the administration needed on the client side.

Comment: If you have just 1 or 2 clients (servers, perhaps) that need to communicated encrypted with an server that's off site, it's really not a big deal. Message security works in that case. But if the WCF host is supposed to talk with 10k portable devices out there, then you've got a real problem, because managing the distribution and installation of all those certs on those 10k computers will be more work and more headache than all the rest of the project combined.